# Tomcat logging proxy IP with RemoteIpValve

Tags: tomcat9

We have a Tomcat 9 configuration with an internal proxy where the users are connecting through (192.168.87.60):

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" internalProxies="10\.4\.68\.85|192\.168\.87\.60" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
            requestAttributesEnabled="true"
                   pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i  &quot;%m %U%{sanitized.query}r %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{sanitized.referer}r&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;"/>
```

but we still see proxy IP in logged lines:

```
49.205.138.100, 192.168.87.60 181x1153x1 ad_xxxxxx [21/Apr/2023:03:01:55 -0700] "POST /rest/structure/2.0/generation/generatorDescriptions?loggedIn=true HTTP/1.1" 200 44 5 "https://xxxx.yyyy.zzz/secure/StructureBoard.jspa?s=6592" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "7bbw3c"
192.168.87.59 182x1155x2 - [21/Apr/2023:03:02:01 -0700] "HEAD /- HTTP/1.0" 200 - 76 "-" "-" "-"
```

in the first line above, we see both IP addresses although 192.168.87.60 is the proxy IP and should not show. any idea about how to fix or why it happens?
I tested with a squid proxy and could not reproduce.